# Search and return multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, search, spreadsheet

This is my problem. I have a spreadsheet containing alot of data. What I want to do is create a way that I can search for a recurring name, and return all the information (rows) associated to it. Here is a mini example below:

```
A    B      C        D          E        F

ID   Name   Date     Client ID  Balance  Owed

100  Tom    1/11/11  256        300      200
100  Tom    1/12/11  565        500      150
100  Tom
200  Jay
200  Jay
300  Frank
100  Tom
100  Tom
400  Ted
```

You get the idea (I hope). So what I want to do on another sheet is search for "Tom" and get it to return ALL instances of Tom in the Name column and return the data in the rows associated to Tom. So I would get back 5 results of Tom with all the necessary information.   Thanks in advance!

B

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Searching and Return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972587/excel-searching-and-return)

Comment: I have added an answer to your duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972587/excel-searching-and-return/4973719#4973719

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pivot Table option found in the Excel, this might help you without any coding, if all you need is to find some duplicates

Comment: I have not tried that option. I essentially want to create it so the name of the person can look at their information only and see trends, etc. from a master list of 20 other names. I want to be able to add to the master list and of course it be updated once I choose which name I want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Could just apply a filter to the data and have the user select their name from column B.  No need to copy data this way, so the update issue goes away. (probably best to delete the blank row below the heading row first)